# Why does a ball appear when I select a bone in pose mode

Tags: 3d-view, bones

When I use plugin Mr Mannequins Tools, I find that when I click some bones in pose mode, a ball like a gizmo will appear like this

[image]

You can hide it by turning off Relationship Lines in Viewport Overlays, but I want to know what it is and how to add and delete it.
Thank you :)

Comment: "Mr Mannequins Tools" must be a third-party addon and questions about it are off topic here. Try asking on the web site that hosts it.

Comment: So this ball is unique to this plugin, and does it not exist in ordinary Blender?

Comment: Yes it is. Presumably the addon is accessing the code to draw it using python.

Comment: See [Custom Shapes](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/armatures/bones/properties/display.html) in the Blender manual.

Comment: OK, I try to reset the coustom shape, but only the bone have changed back, the ball is still there, maybe as you said, it was drawn with python. But anyway, thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a limit rotation overlay ...

Limit set to full range ...
[image]

Limit set to 90°
[image]

Comment: wow, is this! thank you for your answer. It's very helpful to me